# Conflito de tipos na função

Tags: c, struct, lista

Estou tentando criar uma estrutura de lista utilizando `struct`.

Só que ao compilar meu código, recebo um erro pois, mesmo especificando o tipo `Lista`, ele está com algum problema.

Segue o código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct lista {
    int info;
    struct lista* prox;
};

typedef struct lista Lista;

int main(void)
{
    Lista* l; 
    l = list_new();
    l = list_add(l, 23);
    l = list_add(l, 45);
    list_print ( l ); 
    
    return(0);
}

Lista* list_new (void)
{
    return NULL;
}

Lista* list_add (Lista* l, int i)
{
    Lista* novo = (Lista*) malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    novo -> info = i;
    novo -> prox = l;
    return novo;
}

void list_print (Lista* l)
{
    do {
        printf(“%d\t”,l->info);
        l = l->prox;
    } while (l != NULL); 
}
```

O erro está dando na linha 22:

> [Error] conflicting types for 'list_new':
>
> Lista* list_new (void)

Comment: Você sabe que também pode votar em tudo no site, além de aceitar uma resposta em perguntas suas? Dê uma olhada no [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu [coloquei no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Rvn6Sz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aezcxruc-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/LinkedList.c). E depois de resolver uma série de outros problemas não listados na pergunta o código compilou e rodou perfeitamente.

Se quiser deixar mais explícito e talvez atender algum requisito do compilador que está usando, faça um *cast* no tipo retornado para compatibilizar com o tipo do retorno. Assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct lista {
    int info;
    struct lista* prox;
};

typedef struct lista Lista;

Lista* list_new(void) {
    return (Lista*)NULL;
}

Lista* list_add(Lista* l, int i) {
    Lista* novo = malloc(sizeof(Lista));
    novo -> info = i;
    novo -> prox = l;
    return novo;
}

void list_print(Lista* l) {
    do {
        printf("%d\t",l->info);
        l = l->prox;
    } while (l != NULL); 
}

int main(void) {
    Lista* l = list_new();
    l = list_add(l, 23);
    l = list_add(l, 45);
    list_print(l); 
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/wji5pd). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nguqvvaf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Typing/LinkedList2.c).

Comment: Exacto. Isso mesmo.

Comment: Nossa, estou segundo o que estava na apostila da faculdade. Então está tudo errado.... estou acostumado a linguagens de mais alto nivel.
Valeu pela ajuda!

Comment: @MariodeM.BarrosNeto Sim, começando por usar `conio` que é obsoleta e fora de padrão e que nem era necessário nesse caso, uso errado do `malloc()` organização das funções, falta de um `include`  necessários, sem falar em pequenas inconsistências de estilo. Lamentavelmente apostilas difundidas por aí, até mesmo em faculdades são bem erradas e é preciso tomar muito cuidado. Não observei se há erros de lógico ou outros "invisíveis".

Answer (score 1):

Simples, você diz que a função `list_new` retorna do tipo `Lista` e depois está retornando `NULL`:

```
Lista* list_new (void)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Mas eu estou retornando um ponteiro de Lista, e nesse caso, um ponteiro não poderia ser NULL?

Comment: Faz o cast do NULL.